# find the elapsed time between two dates in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, date-arithmetic

i need to find the difference between the time  in the format hh:mm:ss

```
select msglog.id,max(msglog.timestamp) enddate,
   min(msglog.timestamp) startdate,
   enddate - startdate
   from MESSAGELOG msglog
   group by id
```

In the abovequery msglog.timestamp is of type DATE.

How can I get the elapsed time or diff between the time in the correct format in oracle?

Answer (score 24):

When you subtract two `DATE` values like `enddate - startdate` you get the difference in days with decimal accuracy, so for example 1.5 would mean 1 1/2 days or 36 hours. You can convert that to `HH:MI:SS` using a lot of math, but an easier way is to convert the decimal value to an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` value using the [`NUMTODSINTERVAL`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions108.htm#SQLRF00682) function:

```
  NUMTODSINTERVAL(enddate - startdate, 'DAY')
```

You'd think the `TO_CHAR` function would be able to format this as `HH:MI:SS`, but it doesn't seem to work that way. You can use `EXTRACT` instead, and `TO_CHAR` to make sure you get leading zeros:

```
 TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL(enddate-startdate, 'DAY')), 'FM00')
   || ':' ||
 TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL(enddate-startdate, 'DAY')), 'FM00')
   || ':' ||
 TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL(enddate-startdate, 'DAY')), 'FM00')
```

The `00` part of the format code specifies two digits, with a leading zero if needed. The `FM` part gets rid of the leading space in the formatted result, which is reserved for a negative sign if needed.

Also note that your query gets aggregate values and uses them in the same `SELECT` list. Oracle won't let you do this. Try something like this instead:

```
WITH StartEndByID AS (
  SELECT
    msglog.id,
    NUMTODSINTERVAL(max(msglog.timestamp) - min(msglog.timestamp), 'DAY') elapsed
  FROM messagelog msglog
  GROUP BY id
)
SELECT
  id,
  TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM elapsed), 'FM00') || ':' ||
    TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM elapsed), 'FM00') || ':' ||
    TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM elapsed), 'FM00') AS ElapsedHHMISS
FROM StartEndByID
```

Comment: I like this better than my answer, +1.

Comment: Hi Ed, just curious to know whether NUMTODSINTERVAL works for timestamp intervals?

Comment: @San - the result of [timestamp arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50990) is an `interval` anyway, so you don't need to convert it to one.

Comment: If you subtract a `TIMESTAMP` from a `TIMESTAMP` or a `TIMESTAMP` from a `DATE` Oracle will give you an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` result. You don't need to convert. It's only necessary when subtracting a `DATE` from a `DATE`.

Comment: Thanks Ed and Alex for explanation.. Alex my question was if both end_date and start_date have TIMESTAMP datatype. Sorry I forgot to  mentioned that in last comment... Thanks

Answer (score 20):

Date arithmetic in Oracle results in a number expressed in days. So, to convert to hours, you would multiply by 24 and then `trunc` to get an integral number:

```
trunc(24 * (enddate - startdate))
```

To get minutes, convert the days value to minutes and `mod()` that with 60:

```
mod(trunc(24 * 60 * (enddate - startdate)), 60)
```

For seconds, again convert days to seconds and `mod()` that with 60:

```
mod(trunc(24 * 60 * 60 * (enddate - startdate)), 60)
```

Now you can put these together to get the string value you need.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote @GriffeyDog, and +1 yourself! Your answer will also work well. It comes down to lots of math versus lots of function calls, and I expect some folks may be more comfortable with lots of math.

Answer (score 3):

To get the diff in seconds you can use this

```
select round(24 * 60 * 60* (TO_DATE('2017/02/17 9:32:25', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS') - TO_DATE('2017/02/17 8:30:30', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'))) from dual;
```